# Filter directorie(s) from RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, android, json

So in my quest to learn more about Android Development, while studying a Java Programming book, I came across JSONObject and JSONArray.
After a bit of research, I put together a php script to read the contents of a target directory with the output being a JSON file with enough info to parse with a Java class that my study materials go over.

The only issue is, it has been years since I have touched php and the bit that I put together from several sources is the only bit I can understand - so here is the situation:

How can I filter out from my results (before they are added to my JSON file) an array of exclusions (file and/or directory), e.g.: "@eaDir", "Thumbs.db", ".DS_File", etc.

Here is the code in question:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

/* Run with: php [filename].php /path/to/folder/
    Outputs file_list.json in target folder */

// Where are we running on?
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
    $argument1 = $argv[1];
    $argument2 = $argv[2];
}
else {
    $argument1 = $_GET['argument1'];
    $argument2 = $_GET['argument2'];
}

// Set output dir and file
$out = $argument1 . '/file_list.json';

/*
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Array of allowed file types
 */
$types = Array ('mp3', 'ogg');

if (!isset($argv[1]))
    exit("Must specify a directory to scan\n");

if (!is_dir($argv[1]))
    exit($argv[1]."' is not a directory\n");

/*
 * @name getList
 * @param Array $dir
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Recursively iterates over specified directory
 *           populating array based on array of file extensions
 * @return Array $files
 */
function getList($dir, $types) {
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
        if (in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file))), $types)) {
            $files[] = $file->__toString();
        } 
    }
    return $files; 
}

/*
 * @name getDetails
 * @param Array $dir
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Recursively iterates over specified directory
 *           populating array with details of each file
 * @return Array $files
 */
function getDetails($types, $array)
{
    foreach($types as $type)
    {
        foreach($array as $file)
        {
            if (strcasecmp($type, array_pop(explode('.', $file))) == 0) {
                $files[$type][basename($file)];
                $files[$type][basename($file)]['source'] = $file;
                $files[$type][basename($file)]['size'] = filesize($file);
            }
        }
    }
    return array('files'=>$files);
}

if (!function_exists('json_encode')) {

    /*
     * @name json_encode
     * @param Mixed $val
     * @abstract Alternate emulated json_encode function
     * @return Object $res
     */
    function json_encode($val)
    {
        if (is_string($val)) return '"'.addslashes($val).'"';
        if (is_numeric($val)) return $val;
        if ($val === null) return 'null';
        if ($val === true) return 'true';
        if ($val === false) return 'false';

        $assoc = false;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
            if ($k !== $i++){
                $assoc = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        $res = array();
        foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
            $v = json_encode($v);
            if ($assoc){
                $k = '"'.addslashes($k).'"';
                $v = $k.':'.$v;
            }
            $res[] = $v;
        }
        $res = implode(',', $res);
        return ($assoc)? '{'.$res.'}' : '['.$res.']';
    }
}

/* Open file in write mode */
$fp = fopen($out, 'w');

/* Run application & save file */
fwrite($fp, json_encode(getDetails($types, getList($argv[1], $types))));

/* Close file */
fclose($fp);

exit();
```

I run this on a Synology DS1513+ which is always spitting out directories with the name of @eaDir. This is an indexing process that I disable but comes back on the next update (sometimes after a restart).
I would like to add more files types without having to worry about the script checking the directories I mentioned above.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit:
After a bit more of reading and research, I added a nested if condition to filter out directories, this is the code with the changes included:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

/* Run with: php [filename].php /path/to/folder/
  Outputs file_list.json in target folder */

// Where are we running on?
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
    $argument1 = $argv[1];
    $argument2 = $argv[2];
} else {
    $argument1 = $_GET['argument1'];
    $argument2 = $_GET['argument2'];
}

// Set output dir and file
$out = $argument1 . '/file_list.json';

/*
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Array of allowed file types
 */
$types = ['mp3', 'ogg', 'jpg'];
$ignoreDir = ['@eaDir'];

if (!isset($argv[1])) {
    exit("Must specify a directory to scan\n");
}

if (!is_dir($argv[1])) {
    exit($argv[1] . "' is not a directory\n");
}

/*
 * @name getList
 * @param Array $dir
 * @param Array $types
 * @param Array $ignoreDir
 * @abstract Recursively iterates over specified directory
 *           populating array based on array of file extensions
 *           while ignoring directories specified in ignoreDir
 * @return Array $files
 */

function getList($dir, $types, $ignoreDir) {
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
        if (in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file))), $types)) {
            if (!in_array($it, $ignoreDir)) {
                $files[] = $file->__toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

/*
 * @name getDetails
 * @param Array $dir
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Recursively iterates over specified directory
 *           populating array with details of each file
 * @return Array $files
 */

function getDetails($types, $array) {
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        foreach ($array as $file) {
            if (strcasecmp($type, array_pop(explode('.', $file))) == 0) {
                $files[$type][basename($file)]['name'] = basename($file);
                $files[$type][basename($file)]['size'] = filesize($file);
                $files[$type][basename($file)]['source'] = $file;
                $files[$type][basename($file)]['date'] = date ("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($file));
            }
        }
    }
    return array('files' => $files);
}

if (!function_exists('json_encode')) {

    /*
     * @name json_encode
     * @param Mixed $val
     * @abstract Alternate emulated json_encode function
     * @return Object $res
     */
    function json_encode($val)
    {
        if (is_string($val)) return '"'.addslashes($val).'"';
        if (is_numeric($val)) return $val;
        if ($val === null) return 'null';
        if ($val === true) return 'true';
        if ($val === false) return 'false';

        $assoc = false;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
            if ($k !== $i++){
                $assoc = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        $res = array();
        foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
            $v = json_encode($v);
            if ($assoc){
                $k = '"'.addslashes($k).'"';
                $v = $k.':'.$v;
            }
            $res[] = $v;
        }
        $res = implode(',', $res);
        return ($assoc)? '{'.$res.'}' : '['.$res.']';
    }
}

/* Open file in write mode */
$fp = fopen($out, 'w');

/* Run application & save file */
fwrite($fp, json_encode(getDetails($types, getList($argv[1], $types, $ignoreDir)), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

/* Close file */
fclose($fp);

exit();
```

I am still interested in learning more about how a RecursiveDirectoryIterator can use filters but this is working so far for my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has a similar class called **RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator**

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator.php

If you use this instead of your current recursive iterator it will let you "pre-filter" before you iterate over each file/directory.

You can filter by whatever you want including directories, filenames, filesizes etc.

You can then exclude directories like this:

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('dirYouWantToIterateOver');

//define the directories you don't want to include
$excludeDirs = array('@eaDir', 'notThisDir', 'notInThisOtherDir');

$files = new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($dir, function($file, $key, $iterator) use ($excludeDirs){
    if($iterator->hasChildren() && !in_array($file->getFilename(), $excludeDirs)){
        return true;
    }
    return $file->isFile();
});

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($files) as $file){
  //do something with each file
  echo($file->getPathname() . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of this class - I'm using NetBeans to try and implement this into the code I posted earlier but I am hitting a few roadblocks - I can do some really good C and Java, but php needs to be my next language to learn - and so I am stuck.
Any examples on how I can add this to the source provided above?

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution to pinpoint exactly the right folder. E.g. filter "domain.com/this_folder" and not "domain.com/subfolder/this_folder"? If I use $excludeDirs = array('this_folder'), it would filter both, if I use $excludeDirs = array('subfolder/this_folder'), it wouldn't filter any folder

Comment: @Andri not directly that I know of, but you could extend this concept to check for "deeper" folder scenarios. I'll see if I can add an example for this scenario when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out a few days later with a bit of tinkering about.
As mentioned in the original post, the goal was to filter out directories from the results of the recursiveDirectoryIterator, but my script was not complete even then.

I would like to share my completed script, nonetheless. I made use of getID3 in the end, as you will notice:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

/* Run with: php [filename].php /path/to/folder/ /target/folder/
  Outputs $outFileName in target folder */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
require_once('/volume1/auto/getID3/getid3/getid3.php');

// Set output filename
$outFileName = 'file_list_id3.json';
$scanDir = $argv[1];

/*
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Array of allowed file types
 */
$types = ['mp3'];
$ignoreDir = ['@eaDir'];

/*
 * @name getList
 * @param Array $dir
 * @param Array $types
 * @param Array $ignoreDir
 * @abstract Recursively iterates over specified directory
 *           populating array based on array of file extensions
 *           while ignoring directories specified in ignoreDir
 * @return Array $files
 */

function getList($dir, $types, $ignoreDir) {
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
        if (in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file))), $types)) {
            if (!in_array($it, $ignoreDir)) {
                $files[] = $file->__toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

/*
 * @name getDetails
 * @param Array $dir
 * @param Array $types
 * @abstract Recursively iterates over specified directory
 *           populating array with details of each file
 * @return Array $files
 */

function getDetails($types, $array) {
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $getID3 = new getID3;                                                   // Initialize getID3 engine
        $getID3->encoding = 'UTF-8';
        foreach ($array as $file) {
            if (strcasecmp($type, array_pop(explode('.', $file))) == 0) {
                $info = $getID3->analyze($file);                                // Analyse each file
                getid3_lib::CopyTagsToComments($info);                          // Copy tags to comments
                $title = $info['tags']['id3v2']['title'][0];                    // title from ID3v2
                $album = $info['tags']['id3v2']['album'][0];                    // album from ID3v2
                $artist = $info['tags']['id3v2']['artist'][0];                  // artist from ID3v2
                $genre = $info['comments_html']['genre'][0];                    // genre from best source
                $year = $info['comments_html']['year'][0];                      // year from best source
                $source = $info['filename'];                                    // filename only, no path
                $track = $info['comments_html']['track'][0];                    // attempt to grab a tracknumber
                $trackInt = $info['comments']['track'][0];                      // attempt to grab a tracknumber [Integer]
                $bitrate = round($info['audio']['bitrate'] / 1000).' Kbps';     // audio bitrate
                $size = filesize($file);                                        // get file size
                $duration = $info['playtime_string'];                           // playtime in minutes:seconds, formatted string
                $durationLong = $info['playtime_seconds'];                      // playing time of file, in seconds
                $site = str_replace("mp3", "", $info['filepath']);              // path to file, not including filename nor enclosing folder                                
                if(isset($album)){                                              // check for album
                    $imageName = $album.'.jpg';                                 // save imagename as albumname.jpg
                } else {
                    $imageName = str_replace(".mp3",".jpg", basename($file));   // replace [filename].mp3 with [filename].jpg
                }
                if(isset($info['comments']['picture']['0']['data'])){           // check for image
                    $image = $info['comments']['picture']['0']['data'];         // grab image
                    if(file_put_contents($site.'img/'.$imageName, $image));     // save image
                }
                $details = array(
                    'title' => $title,
                    'album' => $album,
                    'artist' => $artist,
                    'genre' => $genre,
                    'year' => $year,
                    'source' => $source,
                    'image' => $imageName,
                    'track' => $track,
                    'trackInt' => $trackInt,
                    'size' => $size,
                    'bitrate' => $bitrate,
                    'duration' => $duration,
                    'durationLong' => $durationLong,
                    'site' => $site
                );
            $files[$type][] = $details;
            }
        }
    }
    return array('media' => $files);
}

/* Set output directory and filename */
$out = $scanDir .'../json/'. $outFileName;
$scan = $scanDir . 'mp3/';
/* Open file in write mode */
$fp = fopen($out, 'w');
/* Run application & save file */
$to_encode = getDetails($types, getList($scan, $types, $ignoreDir));
fwrite($fp, json_encode($to_encode, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
/* Close file */
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Then end result, a script that reads in several mp3 files in a directory, and spits out a properly formatted JSON file, ready for parsing in Android, etc, along with images to go along with your project, if needed - all while ignoring specified files and/or directories (I only have to deal with @eaDir on my server).

The JSON file is saved on a json folder, while the images are saved to an img folder one level up from the mp3 files - keeping things tidy.