# Remove folders in an RecursiveIteratorIterator object

Tags: php

I'm using `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to help make backups of files.
The current script is similar to this one:

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
  $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
  if (strpos($filePath,"unwanted_folder") !== false {
    // do nothing
  } else {
    add_to_zip($file);
  }
}
```

This works fine for most things (I'm using this for many different things). But for certain folders, where I've got a lot of files in the unwanted_folder folder (100,000 images in one instance), it takes a lot of time just to loop through each file of the unwanted folder and I'm running out of execution time.

Is there any way for me to remove the unwanted folders from the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` object without looping through the whole thing? Or, better yet, not have the folder included in the first place when the object is created?

**Edit**
I've now started using this method:[Filter directorie(s) from RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296838/filter-directories-from-recursivedirectoryiterator), which does what I was asking for the most part. The only thing that's bothering me is that I can't pinpoint exactly which folders to filter. If I filter folders called "images" I would filter both "domain.com/images" and "domain.com/subfolder/images". But I can make it work. If anyone has a solution to that, that would be great.

Comment: any filesystem-related iteration of 100k objects sounds like it'll be time consuming and memory intensive. To remove a dir full of stuff, you might consider [exec](https://php.net/exec) and the command `rm -fr unwanted_folder`

Comment: also `zip -r backup.zip original_folder -x unwanted_folder/\*` would work, PHP is bad when it comes to this kind of stuff esp with 100k files, reminds me of applying iptables rules individually which loop though k's of items, vs building a file an loading it into iptables direct, one takes 2hours the other takes 2ms

Comment: I'm not trying to backup the 100k files. That's the whole point. I'm sending my scripts to Dropbox and don't want to backup the images.